# assembler programming - meaning of column

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to learn about assembler programming, so I have an assembler program, but I can't follow the meaning of the first column.

```
declare register DR(11:0), AR(7:0), PC(7:0), IR(3:0)
declare memory MEM(AR,DR)

FETCH:  AR<-PC;
        read M;
        IR<-DR(11:8), PC<-PC+1

        if IR = 10 then goto ADD else

        else goto FETCH  fi;
```

This is a part of the programm. The assembler executes this command:

```
$0:
   $A00;
```

What does the '$' and the three digits mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` prefix in different `Assemblers` (`NASM`, for example) means that a following number is a hexadecimal value. It is `Borland Pascal` and `Motorola Assemblers` style notation. Like this: `$AB`.

There are also other notations: `0x` prefix (like this: `0xAB`) is C-style hexadecimal notation, and `h` postfix (like this `0ABh`) - `MASM/TASM` style. With `MASM/TASM` style a good practice is to use leading zeroes as without them `Assembler` could confuse with a label a hexadecimal that starts with a letter instead of digit.

In your example `$0` seems to be a label and `$A00;` - a data value that can be accessed through `$0` label. Depending of your program context `$A00;`could be also opcode of `CPU`  instructon that will be executed when control flow will reach `$0` label.

Comment: Perfect! And what does the 'A00' mean? Is A a hexadecimal value for `if IR = 10` and the other digitshave other meanings?

Comment: Nothing, just was taken for example

Comment: But what does it mean in my example?